# How to configure Security alerts for web application which is hosted in AZURE VM using windows security center

Tags: azure, security

I have an web application which is deployed an on one of the VM. I would like to scan that application to find the vulnerabilities\attacks list. I installed Qulays and Microsoft management agent but i didn't find any vulnerabilities list and also security alerts also not listed. could you please help me how to get security alerts of my application which is hosted on azure.